# Best way to structure a parser class

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on a project where I need to parse a text file and use that information to do some data manipulation.

I have a parser class and in which I use an array to store my data from the text file. Then I have a separate class that uses this data. My current setup is something like this (pseudo-code obviously) :

```
class Parser{

private:
 array parsedData;

public:
 inline array getParsedData(){
     return parsedData;
 }

};

class algorithms{


//functions that use data from parsedData array;

};
```

I feel like it's rather inefficient to just have a private array that and then just have a public function that just returns the array that I can throw around. I feel like there is a better way to structure this. Any suggestions on how I should structure my code?

Answer (score 2):

You are right to be concerned because there are quite a few issues here:

- Will your parser be reused?
- Does it need to be thread-safe?
- Are you parsing a massive text file, in which case buffering the parsed data will be less effective than "streaming" it.

If you have a relatively small text file and you want to use your parser only once on a single thread, then you *could*:

- Initialize the array to null
- Make sure the array field is private and has no setters
- Have a `parse` method which will read the text file and set the value of the array field
- Have `parse` throw an exception if the array field is not null.

HOWEVER, that's complicated.  Another approach for small text files but you need to parse multiple times:

- The parser will have only a single static method called `parse` which takes in the text file and returns the parsed token array.

The nice thing about the single-method approach is that you don't need the complication of managing the token array as a stateful thing.  And you have a smaller interface, which is nice.

Finally if you have a large text file, have your parse method produce the tokens as a stream.

Answer (score 1):

In Java at least the "return parsedData" will return a reference to your "private array".

The calling program can then do anything it likes with the parsedData;

So it is very efficient as only an address is passed, but, if your intention was to keep a private immutable copy within your class then you would need to return a copy of parsedData which would be less efficient.

In c++ you would need to explicitly return a reference or a copy, but, in Java a reference is all you could return.

Comment: but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: +1 Good point about the need for immutability!  This is, IMHO, a good reason to avoid the class and return the parsed data from a method.